# how to map complex json data into model class

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

**about project:** I am using following [free api](https://geocoding-api.open-meteo.com/v1/search?name=Berlin) to get weather data. I am able to create `Model` class and map basic values and its working ok.

**Question:** But how do I map more complex values like `hourly_units`, which had sub parameters like `time` & `temperature_2m`. same thing about `hourly` which also has arrays of `time` & `temperature_2m`. Do I have to create multi Model class? or can this be doing with List?

```
public class WeatherModel
{
    public long latitude { get; set; }
    public long longitude { get; set; }
    public long generationtime_ms { get; set; }
    public long utc_offset_seconds { get; set; }

    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public string timezone_abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
}
```

JSON return is in following format:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to create it as a class under string elevation? like public class hourly_units{ and inside do the get and set for time and temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried creating them as sub classes

```
public class WeatherModel
{
    public long latitude { get; set; }
    public long longitude { get; set; }
    public long generationtime_ms { get; set; }
    public long utc_offset_seconds { get; set; }

    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public string timezone_abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
    
    Public class Hourly_Units {
         public string time { get; set; }
         public string temperature_2m { get; set; } 
    }   
    Public class Hourly {
         public List<string> time { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Comment: is `public string time` a array or just string?

Comment: you will put whatever the returned data gives you. I simply answered the format you can map the class to the returned json. you have to make sure when you deserialize to check documentation to see if it is a string or list. it does seem like a list from the image provided